# Add a Custom Tab to Custom Media Requester Screen

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am working on a custom theme in which I have created an instance of the WordPress media uploader to upload video files to a given section. Here is my JS code:

```
//click function on the video requester
        $('.video_requester')
            .on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var divisionID = String(e.target.id); // the id of the clicked div
                var custom_uploader = wp.media({
                        title: 'Add Video To Section',
                        button: {
                            text: 'Save Video'
                        },
                        library: {
                            type: 'video'
                        },
                        multiple: false, // Set this to true to allow multiple files to be selected
                        //frame:     'post'// uncomment to see the post frame

                    })
                    .on('select', function () {
                        var attachment = custom_uploader.state()
                            .get('selection')
                            .first()
                            .toJSON();
                        var extension = attachment.url.substr((attachment.url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)); //read what is after the last.
                        alert(attachment.url);
                    })
                    .open();
            });
```

I want to add an extra tab to the media requester pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this post http://pucksart.com/wordpress-javascript-media-library/ there is something that can help you. Basically you have to extend the media library router, adding a new value (for the new tab)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had already achieved this using some other complicated hack (creating my own view) but the modal doesn't close when you interact with the custom view. This looks really clean and promising. Will post my complete code here soon.